# How to query multiple fields with SelectTokens?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

If I've got a JSON array and I want to extract one field from each object, it's fairly simple:

```
Data:
{ 
  "Values": [
    {
      "Name": "Bill",
      "Age": "25",
      "Address": "1234 Easy St."
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bob",
      "Age": "28",
      "Address": "1600 Pennsylvania Ave."
    },
    {
      "Name": "Joe",
      "Age": "31",
      "Address": "653 28th St NW"
    }
  ]
}

Query:
data.SelectTokens("Values[*].Name")
```

This will give me an array of all the names.  But what if I want more than one field?  Is there any way to get an array of objects containing names and addresses?

The obvious way is to run `SelectTokens` twice and then `Zip` them, but will that work?  Are the two result arrays guaranteed to preserve the ordering of the original source data?  And is there a simpler way that can do it with just one query?

Comment: What are you working with, code certainly helps us in helping you.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Working with Newtonsoft.Json, as per the "json.net" tag.  I have the data in a `JObject`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the union operator `['Name','Address']` to select the values of multiple properties simultaneously.  However, at some point you're going to need to generate *new objects* containing just the required properties, for instance by grouping them by parent object:

```
var query = data.SelectTokens("Values[*]['Name','Address']")
    .Select(v => (JProperty)v.Parent) // Get parent JProperty (which encapsulates name as well as value)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Parent)           // Group by parent JObject
    .Select(g => new JObject(g));     // Create a new object with the filtered properties
```

While this works and uses only one [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query, it feels a little overly complex.  I'd suggest just selecting for the objects, then using a nested query to get the required properties like so:

```
var query = data.SelectTokens("Values[*]")
    .OfType<JObject>()
    .Select(o => new JObject(o.Property("Name"), o.Property("Address")));
```

Or maybe

```
var query = data.SelectTokens("Values[*]")
    .Select(o => new JObject(o.SelectTokens("['Name','Address']").Select(v => (JProperty)v.Parent)));
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E9uzAf).

Comment: That's slick, nice explanation and examples!